# Single out and sum a specific variable in a listbox VB

Tags: vba

so I need to sum a listbox to find the totals, this works fine when I'm just using integers; but I need to specificly grab and total just the integers of the string. As it's current like:

"Hello 1"
"Hello 2"
"Hello 3"

So the total should equal 6 (1 + 2 + 3), but it errors 'cause its trying to add the string aswell and not just the integers in each line of the listbox. Heres what I've got.

```
Private Sub Combobox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cart.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim total As Integer

    For Each item As String In Cart.Items
        total = total + item
    Next
    TotalCost.Text = total.ToString

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Addbasket.Click

    Dim pricetotal
    pricetotal = Price.Text * Quantity.Text

    Cart.Items.Add(Products.Text & " £" & pricetotal)

End Sub
```

So the first one displays the list and calculates the total and changes the label and the second one adds the products to the listbox.

Help! :)

Comment: Just curious, what should happen if your string was "2 Hello 1" or "2 hello 4 world", etc.? Are the positions of the numbers fixed, i.e. always at the end separated by a space character? If so, search for the last space and consider everything after that a number. But what if it is "Hello 1 4"? You need to specify a format, otherwise there's just too much uncertainty to go on.

Comment: @djikay Good point! So it's always fixed, doesn't change. It will always be "Text 1", actually it'll be "Text £1". If that helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that your data will always have a number after the last space, this should strip the integer from the overall text.

```
total = total + Int32.Parse(item.Substring(item.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1))
```

Comment: Thanks! I just changed (' ') to ("£") And it takes it from after the £. Brilliant. :)